# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Random.nextInt(int)' on a null object reference [Android]

Tags: java, android, random, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to use the rng from java when I click a button but each time I click it the program crashes and gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Random.nextInt(int)' on a null object reference
at me.test.first.MainActivity.onGenPress(MainActivity.java:25)
```

Button Press Method

```
public void onGenPress(View v){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.string.copper);
        int number = 1 + dice.nextInt(rollProgressMA);
        co.copper += number;
        tv.setText("Copper: " + co.copper + " + " + number);
}
```

Objects involved in class

```
CoinTracker co = new CoinTracker();
RollProgress rpo = new RollProgress();
private Random dice;
private int rollProgressMA = rpo.rollProgress;
```

Int value from RollProgress class

```
public int rollProgress = 1;
```

Thanks in advance for any attempts at solving/solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`private Random dice;`

I don't see any code that initializes the `dice` variable before you use it in `dice.nextInt(rollProgressMA);`.

Just change the declaration to :

`private Random dice = new Random();`

Comment: I've actually tried that before and it didn't work. Just out of curiosity, how is this different from just private Random dice?

Comment: @Tertles `private Random dice;` is equivalent to `private Random dice= null;` You have to assign a `Random` instance before using this variable.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, that fixed the random problem, the exceptions have changed. Thanks you! :-)