# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Random.nextInt(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, random

I've got the exact problem as the question: [Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Random.nextInt(int)' on a null object reference [Android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562162/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-int-java-util-random-nextintint-on-a-null-o) . But I've already instanceiated the Random variable with Random but it still doesn't work. Anyone knows why?

```
.
.
.
import java.util.Random;

public class game_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView gameProblem;
    private int leftNumber;
    private int rightNumber;
    private EditText solution;
    private String operator;
    private int sum;

    private Random r = new Random();

    private int difficulty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_page);
        gameProblem = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.game_problem);
        solution = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.solution);

        setDifficulty();
        newProblem();
    }

    //1 = easy
    private void setDifficulty() {
        this.difficulty = 1;
    }

    private void newProblem() {
        if(difficulty == 1){
            leftNumber = r.nextInt(0) + 10;
            rightNumber = r.nextInt(0) + 10;
            operator = "+";
            sum = Integer.parseInt(leftNumber + operator + rightNumber);
            gameProblem.setText(leftNumber + operator + rightNumber + "=");
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace as requested:

```
10-09 21:46:51.793 4867-4867/benlab.app1ben E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: benlab.app1ben, PID: 4867
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{benlab.app1ben/benlab.app1ben.game_page}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Random.nextInt()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.Random.nextInt()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at benlab.app1ben.game_page.newProblem(game_page.java:47)
                                                                  at benlab.app1ben.game_page.onCreate(game_page.java:33)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6285)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1391) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Stacktrace, please.

Comment: Are you sure the error is in this class?

Comment: Hint: no matter what you do *sum = Integer.parseInt(leftNumber + operator + rightNumber);* will not work in any case. You can only parse **numbers**, not **expressions** like "1 + 2"!

Comment: @GhostCat no the code doesn't even go there. I deal with that later.

Comment: The only way I can see that happening is if something else is setting `r` to null. Make the field `final`, see where the compiler complains.

Comment: @AndyTurner seems to work putting final on random, but now I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0 instead.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho [the parameter to `Random.nextInt()` must be positive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)).

Comment: @AndyTurner seems like it works now, thanks!.